Source and Resource root folder in IntelliJIDEA
I am doing the To Do Application in IntelliJIDEA. The project structure of my project is given right here
Project Structure
I encountered a problem that when I want to use the method of DataBase.java file in LoginController, it seems that the program is not recognize DataBase, even though I have import it into LoginController.
In my point of view, I think that there are some conflicts between the source root and resource root folder, however I cannot find any explanation about this issue online.
I am extremely appreciating that you guys can help me point out the actual problem and how to fix this. Thank you.

The convention is to have all source code under src/main/, do move your DataBase.java under that folder, too. You could also change IntelliJ's build / sorce path settings, but I'd  recommend against that. Stick with standard conventions. Also please don't post images of text; see [ask].
